# Jquery Treeview - prevent other node from collapsing when another node is expanded

Tags: jquery, treeview

I am using Jquery Treeview and one problem I am facing is, when you expand a node an already opened node collapses.

Is there any way to prevent it?

Currently I am using

```
$(document).ready(function(){


    $("#navigation").treeview({
        persist: "location",
        collapsed: true,
        unique: true
    });


});
```

I would just like to have the nodes opened as they are by the user, unless one chooses to close them manually.

Comment: Is this the one you mean? http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-treeview/.  Or this http://www.jstree.com/demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the unique option.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#navigation").treeview({
    persist: "location",
    collapsed: true
  });
});
```

HTH